# quantum circuits in tikz (quantikz) modifying of a command, or how to address nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

Sorry I am not very familiar with this.

I am using quantikz package to draw quantum circuits.
There is an otherwise undocumented feature

```
\begin{tikzcd}
& \makeebit[-60][blue]{test} & \qw & \qw \\
& & \qw & \qw
\end{tikzcd}
```

I would like to modify the command so that it can connect not the two consecutive lines but let's say line 1 and 3 with something in between.

I tried to look into the sourcecode:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\makeebit}{O{-45}O{}m}{
    \arrow[arrows,line cap=round,to path={(\tikztostart) -- ($(\tikztostart)!{0.5/cos(#1)}!#1:(\tikztotarget)$) node [anchor=east,style={#2}]{#3} -- (\tikztotarget) }]{d}
}
```

However, I am not sure how it works with nodes.
Can someone please give me an advice or direct me?

Best wishes

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Could you maybe also somehow show us what you have in mind? Which lines do you mean with "line 1 and 3"?